# Letting a device access the Internet through an Ethernet port via a laptop

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ip, connection-sharing

I have Internet access to my laptop, over Wi-Fi. I have connected a device with an Ethernet port (with an Ethernet cable from my laptop to the device), and set up a local area network between the two, so that they can ping each other. Now I want the device to access the Internet, i.e., to forward "Internet" from Wi-Fi on my laptop to the Ethernet port of the laptop.

How do I set this up if the laptop runs Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up so-called Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).  In general you'll need to assign a static address to the ethernet port on your laptop, then configure `dnsmasq` (DHCP/DNS server) and `iptables` (firewall) on it.

Fortunately Ubuntu has decent support for ICS with GUI (`/usr/bin/nm-connection-editor`), see [this question at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/359856/418498) which also just fits your situation.  If you want to set up everything with your own configuration, refer to [community wiki resources](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq) and [this](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).